# Stored Procedure Not Working In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I have a stored procedure for login user. But it is not working. Here is the code:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[login]
    @username varchar(15),
    @password varchar(250)
AS
    SELECT [User_Username] 
    FROM [dbo].[LOGIN_DETAIL] 
    WHERE User_Username = @username 
      AND Login_Password = HASHBYTES ('SHA2_512', @password + CAST(Salt_Password AS varchar(250)))
```

I am using hash and salt for encryption. Is it something went wrong with the query? Thanks

Comment: Can you define "not working"?

Comment: How are you creating the *original* hash? Are you sure the stored procedure that *updates* the password hash works the same way?

Comment: sql server 2016. actually I am following this link : [link] (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/)

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Consider that the users are putting their trust in you to provide good security.

Comment: I want to know whether the query is ok or something need to change. Thanks

Comment: You aren't going to get any useful responses until you provide useful information.

Comment: @SyedHasan, do you think your query is ok, or must something change to get the results you want? If you say your query is "not working", do you think it is ok? Please post some more information for us. We are happy to help, but we are not mind readers.

Comment: well.. I am a bit confused about the login procedure. Here the password is hashed and salt is having separate column. It is hard to make it clear as I cant find any way to attach the screenshot of my tables.

Comment: Well you can attach images it's the icon in the editor after the {} symbol. Just be sure you can see it  inline in the preview before before posting, I often see people inserting links instead, which just creates confusion having to open multiple tabs etc.. If you're on a Mac you can invoke grab with CMD/SHIFT 3 or CMD/SHIFT 4 - CTRL P (so long since I've used Windows . printscr maybe instead of P)  on a Windows and use something like Paint to paste from clipboard, then edit image to capture specific part.